# How to create the GCP workload identity IAM bindings in Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-iam

GCP allows the Kubernetes service account to impersonate the IAM service account by adding an IAM policy binding between the two service accounts. This binding allows the Kubernetes service account to act as the IAM service account.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[NAMESPACE/KSA_NAME]"
```

We would like to create the same via Terraform resource and we tried this way, refer: [article](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam#google_service_account_iam_binding)

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "service-account-iam" {
  service_account_id = "GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[NAMESPACE/KSA_NAME]",
  ]
}
```

But we received the below error:

> Error: "service_account_id" ("XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com") doesn't match regexp "projects/(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:a-z?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:a-z0-9?)|-)/serviceAccounts/((?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:a-z?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:a-z0-9?))@[a-z]+.gserviceaccount.com$|[0-9]{1,20}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com|a-z@[-a-z0-9\.]{1,63}\.iam\.gserviceaccount\.com$)"

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service_account_id` is the fully-qualified name of the service account to apply the policy to.

`projects/PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

Comment: Hey, @john that worked. Thanks for the super prompt answer

Comment: How were you able to pass the values for PROJECT_ID and SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL ?
Can you paste your example here

Comment: @Vacca - It is unclear what you are asking or who you are asking. I recommend creating a new post when you have a question.